# change fonstize for all objects / axes in a figure

Tags: matlab, plot

When doing multiple plots (`subplot()`, `plotyy()`,... ), how can one adjust to fontsize of all text in the figure?

I am currently using

```
ax = findobj(gcf,'type','axes');
set(ax,'FontSize',13);
```

but would like to scale everything up (title, labels ,...)

Comment: Do you need to do it programmatically? It can be done for all lines and text with a couple clicks in the settings menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time before creating your figures, run:

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontSize',13)
```

Check out [this list of properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) for other defaults you can set.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for objects you can search for any object that has a `FontSize` property.

```
  set(findobj(gcf,'-property','FontSize'),'FontSize',13)
```

To set everything to be 13 point. If you want to scale up by a factor it is a little more work.